# Rename a newly-created directory using Yeoman (mem-fs-editor)

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to rename a folder in the destination directory.  The directory structure inside my `templates` folder looks like this:

```
root/
├── generators
│   └── app
│       ├── templates
│       │   └── app
│       │       └── widget
│       │           ├── widget.controller.ts
│       │           ├── widget.service.ts
│       │           └── widget.module.ts
│       └── index.js
└── .yo-rc.json
```

I'm trying to rename the `widget` directory (in `destinationPath`) to a name that the user enters during the `prompting` stage.  Here's how I'm attempting this:

```
module.exports = generators.Base.extend({
    copyAppTemplate: function () {
        this.fs.copyTpl(this.templatePath('**/*'), this.destinationPath('.'), this.props);

        this.fs.move(
            this.destinationPath('app/widget'),
            this.destinationPath('app/' + this.props.widgetName)
        );
    }
})
```

The call to `copyTpl` is correctly scaffolding and templating the app from the `templatePath` to the `destinationPath`.  However, when the `fs.move` operation is called, I get the following error message:

```
PS C:\Users\username\code\generator-dashboard-widget-test> yo dashboard-widget
? Your widget's name: (generator-dashboard-widget-test)
? Your widget's name: generator-dashboard-widget-test

events.js:154
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^
AssertionError: Trying to copy from a source that does not exist: C:\Users\username\code\generator-dashboard-widget-test\app\widget
    at EditionInterface.exports._copySingle (C:\Users\username\code\generator-dashboard-widget\node_modules\mem-fs-editor\lib\actions\copy.js:45:3)
    at EditionInterface.exports.copy (C:\Users\username\code\generator-dashboard-widget\node_modules\mem-fs-editor\lib\actions\copy.js:23:17)
    at EditionInterface.module.exports [as move] (C:\Users\username\code\generator-dashboard-widget\node_modules\mem-fs-editor\lib\actions\move.js:4:8)
    at module.exports.generators.Base.extend.copyAppTemplate (C:\Users\username\code\generator-dashboard-widget\generators\app\index.js:54:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\username\code\generator-dashboard-widget\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\base.js:431:23)
    at C:\Users\username\code\generator-dashboard-widget\node_modules\run-async\index.js:26:25
    at C:\Users\username\code\generator-dashboard-widget\node_modules\run-async\index.js:25:19
    at C:\Users\username\code\generator-dashboard-widget\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\base.js:432:9
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

From what I understand from the [Yeoman file system documenation](http://yeoman.io/authoring/file-system.html), all actions on the virtual file system are synchronous, so the `app/widget` directory should exist before the `mem-fs-editor` instance attempts to move it.

Is there a different way I should be renaming the directory?

I'm using Yeoman 1.8.4 on Windows 8.1 with node 5.6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't figure out this specific issue, but I was able to accomplish what I was after by using the [`gulp-rename`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) plugin as a transform stream:

```
copyAppTemplate: function () {
    var _this = this;

    // move a file like "app/widget/widget.controller.ts" to 
    // "app/my-widget-name/my-widget-name.controller.ts"
    this.registerTransformStream(rename(function (path) {
        path.dirname = path.dirname.replace('widget', _this.props.widgetName);
        path.basename = path.basename.replace('widget', _this.props.widgetName);
        return path;
    }));

    this.fs.copyTpl(this.templatePath('**/*'), this.destinationPath('.'), this.props);
},
```

I've also opened up a GitHub issue to follow up with this behavior here: https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/455