# Copy all files but change the name of some automatically in yeoman

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am trying to create a yeoman generator where I have to copy from templatePath to destinationPath some files and folders, but I would want to have some of this files with a variable that yeoman could change by one of the user's inputs.

like: "<%=name%>-plugin.php" -> "hello-plugin.php"

I saw some references that this can be done but I can't find how.

I am doing right now:

```
//Copy the configuration files
    app: function () {
      this.fs.copyTpl(
        this.templatePath('**'),
        this.destinationPath(), 
        {
          name: this.props.pluginName,
          name_function: this.props.pluginName.replace('-', '_'),
          name_class: this.props.className,
          description: this.props.pluginDescription
        }
      );
    }
```

I thought that with that code my <%=name%> would magically changed on copyTpl but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible anymore. The feature was bloated and was removed at some point in 2015.

For now, just rename the file:

`this.fs.copy('name.js', 'new-name.js')`

Comment: this renames only one file. What if I have enitre folder with files that need to be renamed using some pattern?

Answer (score 4):

I've just found [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39276789/1804027):

Use `this.registerTransformStream();` to pipe all files through some node.js script.

```
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
//other dependecies...

module.exports = yeoman.Base.extend({

    //some other things generator do...

    writing: function() {
        var THAT = this;
        this.registerTransformStream(rename(function(path) {
            path.basename = path.basename.replace(/(666replacethat666)/g, THAT.props.appName);
            path.dirname = path.dirname.replace(/(666replacethat666)/g, THAT.props.appName);
        }));
        this.fs.copyTpl(
            this.templatePath(),
            this.destinationPath(), {
                appName: this.props.appName
            });
    }
});
```

I'm using here [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) to change file names to something else.

Assuming that `this.props.appName == "myFirstApp"`, this:

> 666replacethat666-controller.html

will change its name to

> myFirstApp-controller.html

Comment: This doesn't work on folders - happen to know of a solution that does?
 -- Cancel that - found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839814/rename-a-newly-created-directory-using-yeoman-mem-fs-editor

Comment: I've updated this answer. You had to just use another gulp script for that. "gulp-replace-name" had many bugs, I replaced it with gulp-rename.

Answer (score 2):

Following @piotrek answer, I made a function to replace all props with some pattern (like ejs does) -> `$$[your prop name]$$`. **warning: ES6 inside**

```
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
//other dependecies...

module.exports = yeoman.Base.extend({

//some other things generator do...

  writing: function() {
    this.registerTransformStream(rename((path) => {
      for (let prop in this.props) {
        let regexp = new RegExp('\\$\\$' + prop + '\\$\\$', 'g')
        path.basename = path.basename.replace(regexp, this.props[prop]);
        path.dirname = path.dirname.replace(regexp, this.props[prop]);
      }
    }));
    this.fs.copyTpl(
        this.templatePath(),
        this.destinationPath(), {
            appName: this.props.appName
        });
    }
});
```

Example:

Let's assume you have `this.props.appname = MyApp` and `this.props.AnotherProps = Test` and you want to rename file or folder.

Name your file or folder `MyFile$$appname$$.js` -> `MyFileMyApp.js`

Name your file or folder `$$appname$$.js` -> `MyApp.js`

Name your file or folder `$$AnotherProps$$.js` -> `Test.js`