# How do I remove .ejs extensions when copying templates from directory?

Tags: node.js, yeoman

I am currently working on a yeoman generator that has to copy a bunch of processed ejs files to setup configuration for a new subproject. In order to avoid listing each file individually, I would like to just take the whole directory and bring over every file with the ejs extension removed and templating applied with the same context.

While searching through the documentation, I eventually ended up looking into the tests of [mem-fs-editor](https://github.com/SBoudrias/mem-fs-editor) and found that `fs.copyTpl` should remove the ejs extensions when using glob patterns [https://github.com/SBoudrias/mem-fs-editor/blob/master/**tests**/copy-tpl.js#L85](https://github.com/SBoudrias/mem-fs-editor/blob/master/__tests__/copy-tpl.js#L85).

However, even when trying to replicate the test in isolated conditions (but within yeoman), the extensions remained:

```
  1 'use strict';                                                                                                                                                      
  2 const Generator = require('yeoman-generator');
  3 const chalk = require('chalk');
  4 const yosay = require('yosay');
  5 
  6 module.exports = class extends Generator {
  7   prompting() {
  8     // Have Yeoman greet the user.
  9     this.log(
 10       yosay(`Welcome to the tiptop ${chalk.red('generator-ejs-glob')} generator!`)
 11     );
 12 
 13     const prompts = [
 14       {
 15         type: 'confirm',
 16         name: 'someAnswer',
 17         message: 'Would you like to enable this option?',
 18         default: true
 19       }
 20     ];
 21 
 22     return this.prompt(prompts).then(props => {
 23       // To access props later use this.props.someAnswer;
 24       this.props = props;
 25     });
 26   }
 27 
 28   writing() {
 29     this.fs.copyTpl(
 30       this.templatePath('ejs/'),
 31       this.destinationPath('out/'),
 32     )
 33   }
 34 
 35 };
```

Where `ejs` contains `file1.txt.ejs` and `file2.txt.ejs`.

The output is

```
> yo ejs-glob                

     _-----_     ╭──────────────────────────╮
    |       |    │   Welcome to the tiptop  │
    |--(o)--|    │    generator-ejs-glob    │
   `---------´   │        generator!        │
    ( _´U`_ )    ╰──────────────────────────╯
    /___A___\   /
     |  ~  |     
   __'.___.'__   
 ´   `  |° ´ Y ` 

? Would you like to enable this option? Yes
   create out/file1.txt.ejs
   create out/file2.txt.ejs
```

I tried changing the path to `ejs/**.*` with no results. When trying to add a `options.processDestinationPath` function myself, it did not even get called.

Do I have to do anything else in order to make this work?

Comment: the documentation says that yeoman uses vinyl fs, a virtual fs in memory, like gulp, whose plugins you can use, if I remember correctly there was one to rename files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gulp-rename`, but I would suggest to use version 1.2.2, there may be some [issue](https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/577) with newer versions, at least I had the problem with the current (2.0.0).

You need to call `this.registerTransformStream`, see:

- [Copy all files but change the name of some automatically in yeoman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48033982/2498790)

I'm using it in a slightly different way, calling my templates `something.optional-ext.ejs` and then removing `.ejs`.

```
  writing() {
    this.registerTransformStream(rename((renamePath) => {
      // remove .ejs extension ans set the real extension if present
      if (renamePath.extname === '.ejs') {
        const lastIndexOfDot = renamePath.basename.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (lastIndexOfDot >= 0) {
          renamePath.extname = renamePath.basename.substr(lastIndexOfDot);
          renamePath.basename = renamePath.basename.substr(0, lastIndexOfDot);
        } else {
          renamePath.extname = '';
        }
      }
      // fix template prefix
      if (renamePath.basename[0] === '_') {
        renamePath.basename = renamePath.basename.slice(1);
      } else {
        renamePath.basename = '.' + renamePath.basename;
      }
    }));
    this.fs.copyTpl(
      this.templatePath(),
      this.destinationPath(), {
          appName: this.props.appName
    });
    // note: write are also affected
    this.fs.write('_props.json', JSON.stringify(this.props));
  }
```